# F# web development - Project

Tags: asp.net, f#

I hadn't used f# before so I installed vs express and then f# package.

After reboot when I went back on vs to create a f# web project like you do with c# that option wasn't there with f#.

Is there any reason that f# can't do this yet is it on the way?

Edit: from the latest f# newsletter here is an article on the f# web project told being developed https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/discussions/541207

Comment: are you using VS2013 or 2012?

Comment: Maybe there aren't default templates for f# web projects. It looks like there are plenary around the web though: http://fsharp.org/webstacks/

Comment: You can install MVC5 and WebApi2 templates [via this extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/39ae8dec-d11a-4ac9-974e-be0fdadec71b)

Comment: You may also want to check out websharper, http://www.websharper.com which compiles F# to javascript.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek     That is the answer, indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently (2017), you can optionally install F# templates via the Visual Studio 2017 installer (under the Web group), .NET core command line, or VS for Mac. Please update your question if this is still an issue.